# Missing symbol in spanish layout keyboard Manjaro KDE

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, kde

I've used a spanish keyboard all my life and until sometime this year, if I needed to write less than or greater than (< or >) I just pressed <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (or <kbd>X</kbd>) to get that. But suddenly all I've got doing that is the symbols ‹ and › (simple spanish quotes). In fact, when reviewing the keyboard layout in settings, this has changed and now looks like this:
[keyboard layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvpS1.png).

How do I revert to the old behavior?

I'm using Manjaro Linux with KDE, and it happened due an update sometime between august and december (2021).